# 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time. How to fix it?

Tags: apache, servlets, extjs, jboss, http-status-code-504

The client requested to download a compressed log file, using [Ext.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs) a form submission on an embedded `iframe`. Request was sent to server, which has [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) and [JBoss 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jboss6.x). The [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlets) compresses log files, do some database operation and returns the compressed file.

Exactly after 2 min, the **504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time** message is seen at the browser net panel. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlets) was taking a long time to compress the log files, and  [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache)'s timeout  was set to 2min.

The error was fixed by increasing the [TimeOut Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) on the [httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpd.conf) file:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
##Timeout 120
Timeout 600
```

Comment: Please notice that this solution might not be acceptable for the user. Instead of making a longer `timeout`, other option could be reviewing the workflow and implement the use case differently. E.g.: one request to start the operation (in this case compression), some notifications of the progress and a final notification with the link to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache error logs. This can also be caused if the file size limit is set too low.

Answer (score 0):

In my case more simply.
I forgot to disable the Proxy extention in the browser.